# Getting the Facebook Shadow Effect on Background Layout Drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, shadow

I want to achieve this shadow effect as a background drawable for my RelativeLayout:

[image]

I am trying to get the denoted effects in my layout. Here's the description:

**A:** Light Stroke **around** the RelativeLayout

**B:** **Shadow** under the layout and a slight shadow to the **right and left** of the layout

What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What more should I add to get the displayed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CardView` also.

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Just add your own elevation and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thank you but how can I achieve it using XML only?

Comment: You can set that CardView as root and then use RelativeLayout for content and just set whatever height or weight you want to it.hope that helps.

Comment: Btw it requires a minimum API of 21. Mine is 15

Comment: Yeah well, that's the point.i've tried that on kitkat it was working btw.there are many materialdesign libraries available also.you may want to take a look.